# Return string and int from a function

Tags: python, json, string

I have a function called item_order (order) that counts the number of char in order and then should returns something like this:

```
'Letter a: number of letter a letter b: number of letter b'
```

But I get an error saying I cannot concatenate str and int. 
How do I return str and int?

This is the code (I am using python):

```
def item_order(order):
     '''
     order is a string containing words for the items a customer can order
     returns the number of times each word is listed
     with this format : name : number of times it is listed
     '''
     s=0
     h=0
     w=0
     for char in order:
         if char=='s':
             s=s+1
         if char=='h':
             h=h+1
         if char=='w':
             w=w+1        
     answer='salad:', s  'hamburger:' h  'water:' w             
     return  answer
```

When I call the function with this argument `('salad, salad, hamburger, water')` I want it to return this:

```
'salad:2 hamburger:1 water:1'
```

I can correctly find the number of times each word is listed but I cannot return it with the above format.

Comment: Please provide code snippet.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Please provide a [minimum, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `format` string method is intended for this kind of task:

```
return 'salad: {} hamburger: {} water: {}'.format(s, h, w)
```

Unrelated: Your counting code is fragile. It happens to work correctly
with this data set, because the letters `shw` only appear once each in
the entire set of words. However, if you added a word like `'milkshake'`
this code would count an extra `s` and `h` every time it appeared.

A better way would be to split the string into words, then look at the
first letter of each:

```
for word in order.split():
    char = word[0]
    if char == 's':
    etc.
```

Even more robust would be to count the words themselves and return a
`dict`, but I’ll leave that to you when you get to dicts; it looks like
you’re just beginning with Python.

Comment: I was aware of the fact that the counting code is weak, however it's ok because salad, hamburger and water are the only words allowed.

Comment: @Cosimo Okay. I hope the ten lines of irrelevant stuff didn’t make you overlook the two lines that answered your question :)

Answer (score -3):

Basically from the requirement which you mentioned, I believe you can try like this in C# :

```
static string OrderInfo(string order)
        {
            int len = order.Length; int count;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                count = 0;
                char toSearch = order[i];

                foreach(char c in order)
                {
                    if (c == toSearch)
                        count++;
                }

                builder.Append("Letter " + order[i] + ": " + count);

            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }
```

Note: This will include the repetitve letters also.